# Photoshop filter gallery in 16bit/channel mode workaround

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there any workaround to use a Photoshop filter from Filter gallery in 16bit/channel mode? 
I need to work in 16/bit for advanced retouching, just need to apply 1 filter from Filter gallery, can I create a 8bit/channel smart object layer in some way just for that 1 filter?

edit: "poster edges" is the filter I like to use for a vintage retouch.

Comment: Telling what filter could help making a alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

Poster edges is one of the most destructive filters. Basicly it reduces the gradients to flat colors. So it does not matter if it is done on 8 bit images.

If you want that in a specific layer you could make a copy of the layer in 8 bits, apply the filter and copy it again into your 16 bit image.

That is just an idea.

Edited to include your solution.

A smart object can be used to embed this layer.

Comment: That idea was indeed the key to the solution!
What I did was duplicate the 16bit layer, make it a smart object, open the smart object, convert the bitmap to 8bit, apply the filter, save and return to the 16bit psd. Did not think of the fact that 8bit mode 'layers' where possible in 16bit mode 'containers'. The existence of smart objects made me feel a little dumb. Thanks for the help!